# Ansible become not switching user

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a playbook that has to complete the following tasks:

- retrieve hostnames and releases from a file *file*
- connect to those hostnames one by one
- retrieve the contents of another file *another_file* in each host that will give us the environment (dev, qa, prod)

so my first task is to retrieve the names of the hosts I need to connect to

```
- name: retrieve nodes
  shell: cat file | grep ";;" | grep foo | grep -v "bar" | sort | uniq
  register: nodes

- adding nodes:
  add_host:
     name: "{{ item }}"
     group: "servers"
  with_items: "{{ nodes.stdout_lines }}"
```

the next task connects to the hosts

```
- hosts: "{{ nodes }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: user1
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: check remote file
      slurp:
        src: /xyz/directory/another_file
      register: thing
    - debug: msg="{{ thing['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

but it doesn't work, when I add verbosity I still see the task being executed with the user running the playbook (local_user)

`<node> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: local_user`

what am I doing wrong?

ansible version is 2.7.1 over rhel 6.1

**UPDATE**

I've also used remote_user: user1

```
- hosts: "{{ nodes }}"
  remote_user: user1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: check remote file
      slurp:
        src: /xyz/directory/another_file
      register: thing
    - debug: msg="{{ thing['content'] | b64decode }}"
```

no luck so far, same error

Comment: Are you able to open an ssh connection from the cli? `ssh user1@host`? This looks like an SSH problem.

Comment: yes, ssh user1@host works perfectly fine without password

Comment: Can you please add the output of your playbook

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `remote_user`, which is the one that controls what username is used when connecting to the server. Only after the connection is established, `become_user` is used.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users

Comment: It would be better to include the relevant information from the link in your answer. Links can expire meaning that future readers may not be able to access the information

Comment: I've tried this as well, but still is running with the local_user, set it to the role and the task, still picking up the local_user :(

Answer (score 0):

if you use `become_user` it is like using `sudo command` on the remote machine.
You want to connect to your machines as a specific user. And after the connection is established issue the commands with `sudo`. 
[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1081609/how-to-set-a-default-ssh-user-for-all-hosts-in-ansible) question has some answers that should help you.